# How to make a new column with a specific condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a new column with this condition:

- If the the value on Case Number column in current row equals with the previous row, then the value should be taken from column 'diff'
- If the current row is not equal with the previous row, then the value should be taken from 'lastmod-start' column.

This is the code that I've tried :

```
df['new'] = [None] * len(df)
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df['Case Number'][i] == df['Case Number'][i-1]:
        df['new'][i] = df['diff']
    else:
        df['new'][i] = df['lastmod-start']
```

However the code above is resulting an error.
Is the anyone can help me? Thank you.

This is the screenshot [The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bulej.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Please consider adding a safe and secure part of the input dataframe and the desired output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `np.where` along with `shift()` for a one line vectorized solution here:

```py
df["new"] = np.where(df["Case Number"] == df["Case Number"].shift(1), df["diff"], df["lastmod-start"])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can assign a new column as a single value and pandas will broadcast it to the entire column.  Since the `'new'` column will be string, you can just initialize it to an empty string.

```
df['new'] = ''
```

Next, if you want to compare each row to the row before it, you can use the `.shift()` method create a boolean index of which rows match.  Then use that index to assign the values.

```
ix = df['Case Number'] == df['Case Number'].shift()
df.loc[ix, 'new'] = 'diff'
df.loc[~ix, 'new'] = 'lastmod-start'
```